# MATLAB Heatmap: Auto Colourisation of Cell Labels

Tags: matlab, fonts, colors, matlab-figure, heatmap

I am plotting four unique datasets on a heatmap; x, y, cell colour, and fourthly, cell labels. The customisable heatmap function [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24253-customizable-heat-maps) provides a simple method of doing so, and also of auto-adjusting the colour of the text font in the heatmap's cells to maintain high contrast relative to the cell background. See screenshot of the .fig below, where text has been automatically changed from black to white as required:

[image: Illegible text enclosed in overlaid orange box]

[image: JPG]

1. If the .fig is saved in any format other than .fig, the text font colour reverts to the default black. The second image, a jpeg saved from the .fig, illustrates. This surprising behaviour is the same if the [export fig](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) or [matlab2tikz](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) packages are used. How can I obtain a .jpeg or other format than .fig and maintain the white font colours? Taking a screenshot will not suffice because I need the image at very high resolution if raster, or in a vector format.
2. Many of the whitened fonts appear granulated or aliased. Thus, they are almost illegible. The worst cases are enclosed in the orange box to highlight them. Is there a fix for this?

MWE:

```
cell_text = 1:1:66;
cell_colour_data = 53:1:(53+65);
upper_colour_lim = max(cell_colour_data);
lower_colour_lim = min(cell_colour_data);
xvalues = 1:1:6;
yvalues = 1:1:11;

figure();
my_colormap = bone;
my_gridlines = '-';

colour_data_layernum = reshape(cell_colour_data,...
    [length(yvalues),...
    length(xvalues)]);
text_data_layernum = reshape(cell_text,...
    [length(yvalues),...
    length(xvalues)]);
clabel = arrayfun(@(x){sprintf('%0.2f',x)}, text_data_layernum);

heatmap_custom(colour_data_layernum, xvalues, yvalues, clabel,...
    'Colormap', my_colormap, 'GridLines', my_gridlines,...
    'TextColor', 'xor',...
    'MinColorValue', lower_colour_lim, 'MaxColorValue', upper_colour_lim);
```

Note that EraseMode is required by this package to instigate the colour switch of the label fonts. Since EraseMode was deprecated with the introduction of Handle Graphics V2, you will need R2014a or earlier to replicate this behaviour.

Note that if the `heatmap.m` file downloaded from this File Exchange package is not renamed, you will have overshadowing issues with MATLAB's `heatmap.m` function that will likely manifest as a subscript indices error. In the MWE above, the downloaded file has been renamed to `heatmap_custom.m`.